# Need help with the phrase "Travel broadcasting platform"

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

we're trying to develop the social media sharing platform. It is a niche-oriented application which is thought to resolve the needs of travellers during the trip. The content created during the travel is shared in the form of story.

Trying to describe the application in a short and concise way we ended up with this  phrase:

> APP-NAME is the travel broadcasting platform

Or can we say?

> Welcome to the travel broadcasting platform

Some questions:

- Does it make any sense to you?
- And especially does it transmit the idea I've described before?

Thank you!

Comment: Why did you use the term 'broadcasting'?  The uniqueness of your project is that you cleverly use narrative stories to help your clients. 'Travel broadcasting  platform' does not sound welcoming, nor touristy

Comment: You aren't broadcasting travel, so I'd suggest changing this word to the possessives "Traveler's" or "Travelers'" or possibly "Traveling."  I agree that "broadcast" needs to be justified -- if you're sending the same content to many recipients it may be appropriate, but otherwise it probably isn't what you had in mind. And "platform" is pure jargon and even then refers to a layer that other things are implemented on top of; it sounds like what you want here is just "system" or some other simple and direct term.

Comment: Thank you very much for the insight!! Really, you gave us some good points to think of, we're programmers so our language maybe too 'technical' and also non of us are native speakers. The one true point is that the landing page should present the so called 'call for action' which is absolutely absent in our technical definition of the app :)

Answer (score 1):

'Broadcasting' gives the impression of television to me and makes me think more about the device rather than the app, which probably isn't what you want.  I think the description should be short and snappy, perhaps using travel-related words like:

- hub
- network

If you are encouraging the travellers to share their experiences in the form of stories, why not try a writing theme?

- the travellers' diary
- the globetrotters' journal

While your original description wasn't bad, it just sounded a bit longwinded in my opinion.